# Mysql - Rows within hourly ranges on specific days using DAYOFWEEK

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a query that will return a result set with reading total within certain hour ranges (defined in the `working_hours` table) depending on the `DAYOFTHEWEEK` for the date with a result that looks like:

```
working | nonworking | weekend | date              | group_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
50.3    | 30.8       | 0       | 2015-04-01 00:00  | 7
40.3    | 60.8       | 0       | 2015-04-01 00:00  | 8
50.3    | 30.8       | 0       | 2015-04-02 00:00  | 7
40.3    | 60.8       | 0       | 2015-04-02 00:00  | 8
```

Working and Weekend ranges are stored in the database in `working_hours`, Nonworking time ranges are implied (`NOT BETWEEN` the other ranges on that day basically)

The tables are as following:

Readings table has the hourly readings, named `readings`

```
group_id     | reading     | datestamp         
------------------------------------------------------
7            | 30.8        | 2015-04-01 00:00  
7            | 20.2        | 2015-04-01 01:00  
7            | 11.2        | 2015-04-02 00:00  
7            | 20.2        | 2015-04-02 01:00  
8            | 26.2        | 2015-04-01 00:00  
8            | 30.2        | 2015-04-01 01:00  
8            | 26.2        | 2015-04-02 00:00  
8            | 30.2        | 2015-04-02 01:00
```

Hour Ranges are stored in the `working_hours` table, the day column is `DAYOFTHEWEEK` format (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc):

```
group_id | day | range_start | range_end | range_type_id | day_type_id 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7        | 5   | 08:00:00    | 15:59:00  | 1             | 1
7        | 6   | 00:00:00    | 05:59:00  | 1             | 2
7        | 6   | 06:00:00    | 23:59:00  | 2             | 2
7        | 1   | 00:00:00    | 22:59:00  | 2             | 4
7        | 1   | 23:00:00    | 23:59:00  | 1             | 4
```

Day Types are in the `working_hours_day_type` table and where things get complicated for me, Weekday and Weekend only have one range but Start/End Weekend have two ranges ('Start Weekend' first range is working hours, second range weekend hours and 'End Weekend' first range is weekend hours, second range working hours).

```
id | type
------------------
1  | Weekday
2  | Start Weekend
3  | Weekend
4  | End Weekend
```

Range Types are in the `working_hours_range_type` table:

```
id | type
------------------
1  | Working
2  | Weekend
```

My Mysql knowledge is limited to simple `SELECT`, `INSERT` etc and the basics of `JOIN`s - I have found out about `HOUR(datestamp) BETWEEN 8 AND 14` but dont know how to get subqueries to iterate within a parent query using `WHERE datestamp BETWEEN '2015-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-02 23:59:00'` if in fact thats how its done...

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. This seems like an overly complex design - or am I missing something? And if columns are irrelevant to the problem, don't include them.

Comment: Am welcome to any suggestions that simplify this, I need to get a daily breakdown of usage (`SUM` of readings) within the ranges specified.  If 1st April is a Sunday, then look at the `working_hours` get any ranges that are specific to Sunday and apply them to the readings on that date to get the total.

Comment: You don't need extra tables for this - you can do all this in the first select using a couple of CASE statements.

Comment: you seem to be missing the working hours for group 8 in your sample data

Comment: @bf2020 care to demonstrate in an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally clear on what constitutes working hours or non-working hours, but does this work?

```
SELECT
 sum(CASE WHEN rtype.range_type_id = 1 THEN reading ELSE 0 END) AS working
 sum(CASE WHEN rtype.range_type_id = 2 THEN reading ELSE 0 END) AS nonworking
 CASE WHEN r1.daynum in (7,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as weekend
 date(datestamp) as date
 r1.group_id 
FROM
    (SELECT
        group_id,
        reading,
        time(datestamp) as rTime,
        case when weekday(datestamp) = 0 THEN 2 #weekday() monday to working hours monday
            when weekday(datestamp) = 1 THEN 3 
            when weekday(datestamp) = 2 THEN 4 
            when weekday(datestamp) = 3 THEN 5 
            when weekday(datestamp) = 4 THEN 6 
            when weekday(datestamp) = 5 THEN 7 
            when weekday(datestamp) = 6 THEN 1 
        else NULL
        END CASE AS daynum
    FROM readings) AS r1
    LEFT JOIN working_hours w1
        ON (r1.daynum = w1.day) 
         AND (r1.group_id = w1.group_id) 
         AND (r1.rTime BETWEEN w1.range_start AND w1.range_end)
    LEFT JOIN working_hours_day_type dtype 
        ON w1.day_type_id = dtype.id 
    LEFT JOIN working_hours_range_type rtype
        ON w1.range_type_id = rtype.id
GROUP BY
 CASE WHEN daynum in (7,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
 date(datestamp) as date,
 r1.group_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it gave me what I needed to get this done!  Instead of nonworking hours being implied I've created a range_type for them (cant join on implied data!) and it has simplified the query a ton:  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e831f/3) - stripped out a lot to get what I needed - not sure if you want to edit yours to whats in the fiddle so I can mark it as right? (there were some typos etc)

Comment: I'm glad it worked, as you can see it was more involved than I thought it would be in my original comment to your question...
I was going to rework the answer according to your comment but the link results in a 404 error when I try to load it.  Is there any aspect of the answer that I can further explain or comment on what the SQL is doing?